# Copying data from one linux machine to another

Tags: shell, expect

I am trying to run a script placed in machine  A  ,in machine B .
This script generates a output file F.
Then I am trying to copy this File F back to machine A .

The command I am using to run the .sh placed in machine A  is

```
ssh root@Machine B 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

The contents of the file "test.sh" (which generates the output and tried to copy it back ) are .

```
#!/bin/bash
memory=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'MemTotal' | awk -F ':' '{print$2}')
processor=$(lscpu | grep 'CPU(s):'|awk -F ':' '{print$2}'|head -1)
socket=$(lscpu | grep 'Socket(s):'|awk -F ':' '{print$2}')
cores=$(lscpu | grep 'Core(s) per socket'|awk -F ':' '{print$2}')
cpuspeed=$(lscpu | grep 'CPU MHz'|awk -F ':' '{print$2}')
echo $memory,$processor,$socket,$cores,$cpuspeed >>server_info.txt   
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn scp /path/server_info.txt  root@MachineA:/path/
expect "Password: "
send "pwd\r"
EOF
```

The whole thing together is not working ,for some reason . What am I doing wrong here

Comment: As an aside, you create around 11 entirely unnecessary processes - you don't need `cat`, `grep` and `awk` - just use `awk '/^MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: `lscpu | awk '/^CPU\(s\)/{print $2; exit}'`

Comment: You should just set up ssh keys appropriately, then you can do something like `ssh user@A 'ssh user@B "bash -s" < script.sh > output'`

Comment: Mark ,thanks for the suggestions , I am just starting to learn shell ,and the suggestions are really helpful .

Comment: Glenn ,the environment I am working in doesn't  allow me to create ssh keys .

Comment: I tried another approach too , after I ssh to to the remote ,and run my script ,the server_info.txt gets saved there ,  then I scp and copy the file back .Although this is working manually ,When I try to put the whole thing in a script and use expect , it does'nt log in